ORDER BY clause
I am hoping you can help me with a query where I want the result set to be ordered in an unusual way. I would be grateful for any help or guidance you can provide.
I have a DB2 table that contains a column I will call CODE, with the values A, B, C, D, E, F (for example). And another column, TIMESTAMP, which represents when the row was inserted into the table.
I would like to order the result set as follows:
If CODE = B or C, then show those rows first (in TIMESTAMP order regardless of the value of CODE, i.e. I don't want the B's before the C's). Then show the remaining rows (also in TIMESTAMP order).
For example:
**C**  2024-**08-01**-12.59.21.177652
**B**  2024-**08-02**-12.59.21.177652
**C**  2024-**08-03**-12.59.21.177652
**D**  2024-**07-20**-12.59.21.177652
**A**  2024-**07-21**-12.59.21.177652
**F**  2024-**07-22**-12.59.21.177652
**E**  2024-**08-20**-12.59.21.177652

I thought I could add a CASE statement to the ORDER BY, but that does not appear to work. I am using DB2 on a z/OS mainframe.

Disclaimer: I don't have access to Db2 in z/OS, so I don't know if the query below will work.
Using subqueries the query can look like:
select code, timestamp
from (
  select code, timestamp, case when code in ('B', 'C') then 0 else 1 end as g
  from t
) x
order by g, timestamp;

See running example, albeit in Db2/LUW.

SELECT CODE, TIMESTAMP
FROM your_table_name

ORDER BY 
CASE 
    WHEN CODE IN ('B', 'C') THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END,
TIMESTAMP;


Db2-for-Z/OS (as specified in the question) does not support CASE in the order-by clause. This answer is not correct for Db2-Z/OS.

This is very helpful. In the WHEN clause, you use THEN 1 ELSE 0. What do the 1 and 0 refer to? Can I substitute column names to make the query more clear?

THEN 1 ELSE 0 is what the order by uses for order. So you get B and C first because they get 0 in the order all others get 1. But as mentioned the case in the order by does not work on db2-z

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
